# Making my IDE take a specific Python version

Tags: python, python-2.7, ide, pycharm

I have Python 2.7.8 installed and when doing the version check in my command line, it shows that I have Python 2.7.8.

However, when I run PyCharm it's running it on version 2.6. Is there a way for me to get it to make PyCharm take the 2.7.8 version?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, PyCharm picks up the Python installed system-wide.

Which Python your project should use is configured under [Project Interpreter](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/project-interpreter.html) section of your Project Settings. From [there](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html), you can add existing interpreters either locals, or remotes, even create brand-new virtual environments and manage packages inside.